# Android - create vertical tab at left using android 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create vertical tab on left. I had done a lot of research from the internet to find the solution. However, when i try to implement the suggested solution, I still failed to get the result that I want. Below is my code, i wish someone can help me to solve my problem. Very much appreciate if someone here can help me.

### main.xml

```
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
        <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
               <TabWidget 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0">
                </TabWidget>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
```

### Java

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Resources res = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Configuration cfg = res.getConfiguration();
        boolean hor = cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        if(hor)
        {
            TabWidget tw = tabHost.getTabWidget();
            tw.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        }

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        Intent intent;

     // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_album))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_song))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

do like below in your application.

```
getTabWidget().setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: Hi Narendra, thanks for your reply. I can make the tab be vertical in left side, but the text that suppose to be displayed in the FrameLayout is being hidden by the tab. Do you have any idea that which part I did wrongly or I need to add any code to make my vertical tab in left and text can successfully displayed in the FrameLayout? Thank you very much